# Excel Unique Function Misfunctioning

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using the Unique function to create a frequency distribution. However, the Unique function is giving me duplicate values. Here is an image of the input data:

[image: Input data: Values: NS MF MF MF Missed]

The Unique function returns MF three times. I thought it might be because there are trailing blanks, so I used the trim function & upper for cases where the data are in lower case (not shown in this particular example). The output is giving me all of the values in my range.

Output data from function =UNIQUE(UPPER(TRIM(Sheet1!H2:Sheet1!L2))), Same as input data:
[image: Output data from function =UNIQUE(UPPER(TRIM(Sheet1!H2:Sheet1!L2))), Same as input data]

Answer (score 1):

By default UNIQUE extracts data by Rows. To force UNIQUE to extract by COLUMN use the second parameter as 1 or TRUE.

```
UNIQUE(H2:L2,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a second argument to the function when dealing with columns

`=UNIQUE(Sheet1!H2:Sheet1!L2,TRUE)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=UPPER((UNIQUE(A1:E1,TRUE)))
```

[image]